# Is there a way to block eventbridge event triggers while lambda is running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have an event trigger for every 5 minutes on my lambda. However, sometimes once my lambda starts running, it needs to run for longer than 5 minutes. Is there any way to have my timeout set for 15 minutes, and block the event triggers from spawning a new lambda while there is a lambda already running? Is this functionality built in?

Comment: See if [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) of 1 works for you. I'm not sure what happens to the scheduled event triggers in this case, however, so you need to test. Another option would be to implement a concurrency lock using DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent an AWS Lambda function running in parallel, you can set the [Reserved Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) to `1`.

While this is intended to guarantee ('reserve') capacity for the function, it also has the result of **limiting concurrent executions** to 1.

If the function takes longer than 15 minutes, it will probably be executed multiple times in the next 15 minute-period, which might impact your code depending on what it is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is put a SQS FIFO queue in the middle between EventBridge and your Lambda. Have EventBridge send the event as an SQS message into the queue. The SQS queue would trigger the lambda. This would ensure your events were processed one at a time, with no overlap.

Note that this approach will queue up your events for execution instead of skipping an event if the Lambda is still running.